# I want to put a countdown timer in a separate method

Tags: android, button, methods, countdowntimer

I want to put my CountDown Timer in a separate method

```
img9.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    public void onClick(View v) {
        img9.setBackgroundResource(myImg9);
        String txt = PName.getText().toString();

        if(txt.equals("Heart")){
            if(myImg9 == R.drawable.heart){
                correct++;
                img9.setBackgroundResource(myImg9);
                new CountDownTimer(1000,1000) {

                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        //This is when you click on each tick it came here after 1000 millisecond
                    }

                    public void onFinish() {
                        // After the time is experied so here can change image

                        img9.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);    
                        img9.setEnabled(false);

                    }
                    }.start();
                } 
     //wrong heart
                else if(txt.equals("Heart")){
                    if(myImg9== R.drawable.circle || myImg9== R.drawable.square || myImg9== R.drawable.triangle){
                        img9.setBackgroundResource(myImg9);
                        new CountDownTimer(1000,1000) {

                            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
               //This is when you click on each tick it came here after 1000 millisecond
                            }

                            public void onFinish() {
                                // After the time is experied so here can change image

                                img9.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);    


                            }
                        }.start();

                    }
     }


     }


            if(txt.equals("Circle")){
                    if(myImg9 == R.drawable.circle){
                        correct++;
                            img9.setBackgroundResource(myImg9);
                    new CountDownTimer(1000,1000) {

                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                            //This is when you click on each tick it came here after 1000 millisecond
                        }

                        public void onFinish() {
                            // After the time is experied so here can change image

                            img9.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);    
                            img9.setEnabled(false);

                        }
                    }.start();
                    } 
        //wrong circle
                    else if(txt.equals("Circle")){
                        if(myImg9== R.drawable.heart || myImg9== R.drawable.square || myImg9== R.drawable.triangle){
                            img9.setBackgroundResource(myImg9);
                            new CountDownTimer(1000,1000) {

                                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                                    //This is when you click on each tick it came here after 1000 millisecond
                                }

                                public void onFinish() {
                                    // After the time is experied so here can change image

                                    img9.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);    


                                }
                            }.start();

                        }
                    }


            }


            if(txt.equals("Triangle")){
                if(myImg9 == R.drawable.triangle){
                    correct++;
                    img9.setBackgroundResource(myImg9);
                    new CountDownTimer(1000,1000) {

                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                            //This is when you click on each tick it came here after 1000 millisecond
                        }

                        public void onFinish() {
                            // After the time is experied so here can change image

                            img9.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);    
                            img9.setEnabled(false);

                        }
                    }.start();
                } 
                //wrong circle
                else if(txt.equals("Triangle")){
                    if(myImg9== R.drawable.heart || myImg9== R.drawable.square || myImg9== R.drawable.circle){
                        img9.setBackgroundResource(myImg9);
                        new CountDownTimer(1000,1000) {

                            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
               //This is when you click on each tick it came here after 1000 millisecond
                            }

                            public void onFinish() {
            // After the time is experied so here can change image

                                img9.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);    


                            }
                        }.start();

                    }
                }


            }




            if(txt.equals("Square")){
                if(myImg9 == R.drawable.square){
                    correct++;
                    img9.setBackgroundResource(myImg9);
                    new CountDownTimer(1000,1000) {

                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                            //This is when you click on each tick it came here after 1000 millisecond
                        }

                        public void onFinish() {
                            // After the time is experied so here can change image

                            img9.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);    
                            img9.setEnabled(false);

                        }
                    }.start();
                } 
                //wrong circle
                else if(txt.equals("Square")){
                    if(myImg9== R.drawable.heart || myImg9== R.drawable.circle || myImg9== R.drawable.triangle){
                        img9.setBackgroundResource(myImg9);
                        new CountDownTimer(1000,1000) {

                            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
               //This is when you click on each tick it came here after 1000 millisecond
                            }

                            public void onFinish() {
            // After the time is experied so here can change image

                                img9.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);    


                            }
                        }.start();
                    }
                }


            }

    }

    });
```

As you can see I call a new CountDownTimer in a lot of conditions. However, I want to put it in a separate method so I can just call it to make my java file much more readable. However, I can't put it in a void method because I have different buttons. Here, I used the CountDownTimer on **img9**. I still have different buttons, namely button **img1** to **img8**. I don't know what kind of method I will use.

What kind of method shall I use to store my CountDownTimer? Kinda new to Android. Please help. Thanks to those will help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want, you want to call the same method to start the `CountDownTimer` from different `ImageButtons`. If this is correct, just set the `onClick` in xml by adding a line like this to each `ImageButton`

```
<ImageButton
   ...
   android:onClick="someFunctino"/>   <!-- add this line to each -->
```

then in your java create this function

```
public void someFunction(View v)
{
     // conditions
     new CountDownTimer(1000,1000) {

                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    //This is when you click on each tick it came here after 1000 millisecond
                }

                public void onFinish() {
                    // After the time is experied so here can change image

                    img9.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);    
                    img9.setEnabled(false);

                }
                }.start();
}
```

I don't quite understand your conditions so I can't help more with that but this way any `Button` clicked with that xml entry will call this function. If you need to know what `Button` was clicked you can use the `id` of `v` which will give you your `Button id` like

```
public void someFunction()
{
    int id = v.getId();  // can compare to id like if (id == R.id.buttonID)
    ...
}
```

And maybe I am misreading but you seem to have

```
if(txt.equals("Heart")){
// some code
else if(txt.equals("Heart")){
```

which is the same condition. If this isn't what you are talking about then please clarify a little.

Also, I think you need to rethink your conditions because I see a lot of repeated code and its a little confusing what's going on. And since you are always using the `CountDownTimer` you can just set it after your conditions one time. I don't understand why you say you can't use a method with a `void` return type.

Comment: I'm creating a memory game. The condition txt.equals("Heart") is used to determine if you have the correct answer.

Comment: I see, it first looked like that `else` was part of the first `if`. Did this solution answer your question on using the function or did I miss what you wanted?